# UK marriage visa

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, weddings, vfs-global

I am an American citizen but don't live in the USA.  I will likely have to fly to the USA for my bio metrics, send the visa then wait for its return. How long does it take to process the visa without paying the "premium" VFS service fees?  I am trying to do this as inexpensively as possible. Is there a better way to do this?  So far, it will cost me the return flight, accommodation while I sit and wait and however many vacation days to sit around and wait for my passport.  Does this seem accurate?

Comment: Why do you think you’ll have to fly to the USA for your biometric appointment? Where are you planning to apply from?

Comment: Where do you live? Can you apply for the visa there?

Comment: I live in Belize and they do not have a visa application center here.  The closest are Panama, Mexico, Colombia or USA.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa the typical timescale for a decision is 3 weeks.

Comment: I am wondering if anyone has any personal experience with this and has gone through the process before - does it normally take as long as the typical timescale?